# Can't mount LUKS encrypted drive

Tags: hard-drive, mount, disk-encryption, luks

Note: [Cross-posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/653121/cant-mount-luks-encrypted-drive)

I have a LUKS encrypted disk that I can unlock, but not mount:

```
$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 disk4tb
# enter key
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/disk4tb
$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/disk4tb /mnt/disk4tb
mount: /mnt/disk4tb: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on 
/dev/mapper/disk4tb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Looking at `dmesg` I see:

```
$ dmesg | tail
[ 1987.080561] F2FS-fs (dm-1): Magic Mismatch, valid(0xf2f52010) - read(0x0)
[ 1987.080573] F2FS-fs (dm-1): Can't find valid F2FS filesystem in 2th superblock
[ 3253.500590] F2FS-fs (dm-1): Magic Mismatch, valid(0xf2f52010) - read(0x0)
[ 3253.500601] F2FS-fs (dm-1): Can't find valid F2FS filesystem in 1th superblock
[ 3253.500934] F2FS-fs (dm-1): Magic Mismatch, valid(0xf2f52010) - read(0x0)
[ 3253.500941] F2FS-fs (dm-1): Can't find valid F2FS filesystem in 2th superblock
[ 3417.866616] F2FS-fs (dm-1): Magic Mismatch, valid(0xf2f52010) - read(0x0)
[ 3417.866626] F2FS-fs (dm-1): Can't find valid F2FS filesystem in 1th superblock
[ 3417.866953] F2FS-fs (dm-1): Magic Mismatch, valid(0xf2f52010) - read(0x0)
[ 3417.866960] F2FS-fs (dm-1): Can't find valid F2FS filesystem in 2th superblock
```

Information:

```
$ fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ST4000DM000-2AE1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 899F5BC4-17D0-4904-AEA6-C753E825F6FC

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 7814035455 7814033408  3.7T Linux filesystem
```

Comment: The issue would appear to be that Linux cant recognise the type of filesystem the drive is using.  Are you able to tell us how  it was created?  (If its a new drive, you meed to mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/disk4tb - but this will erase its contents)

Comment: I formatted as ext4 using the disks utility from gnome on a 20.04 system. Then applied cryptsetup.

Comment: You probably killed your filesystem - your order is wrong.  First you encrypt the drive, then you apply the file system.  It appears you have overwritten your filesystem with pseudorandom data with the command to encrypt the filesystem.

Comment: Thank goodness for back-ups of back-ups!